# Ruby on Rails Twitter App - Associate Current User ID when Creating a new Status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to follow along on a tutorial on a Ruby on Rails Twitter App but as I reached the end I noticed that I don't really like the fact that you can create other user's posts. My wish is just to create your own.

How can I achieve this

```
Status Controller Create:
def create
@status = Status.new(params[:status])
respond_to do |format|
  if @status.save
    format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @status, status: :created, location: @status }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Status Create View as it is currently:

```
...
<div class="field">

<%= f.input :user_id, collection: User.all, label_method: :full_name %>
<%= f.input :content %>
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

Status Model:

```
class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :content, :user_id
belongs_to :user
end
```

Hope anyone can help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some authorization in here!

- Authorization with cancan, a gem by Ryan Bates

  http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan?autoplay=true
- Authorization from scratch pt.1, pt.2

  http://railscasts.com/episodes/385-authorization-from-scratch-part-1?autoplay=true

  http://railscasts.com/episodes/386-authorization-from-scratch-part-2?view=asciicast

---

A more simple way to do this, since you are coding for a tutorial (=> you want to learn), you can work it out with associations.

Inside app/models/user.rb

```
has_many :statuses, dependent: :destroy
```

And remove attr_accessible :user_id from app/models/status.rb

attr_accessible :attribute means that a User can explicitly set the value of this attribute through a form, which you don't want.

Then check in you controller if the user for whom the post is being created, is the current signed in user. If not, don't allow it.

Answer (score 1):

In application controller:

```
def current_user
  User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:uid]
end
```

You'll have to set the session user_id when you authenticate the user.

In your view (using [SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)):

```
  <%= f.input :user_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: current_user.id }%>
```

This will work.  Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks!!! That worked as well but I managed to modify the status controller by adding this and it worked just like I wanted: @status.user = current_user

Comment: That will work as well.  Also depends on your app needs (e.g. if you are developing for API functionality or just HTML rendering, etc.)  Good luck and enjoy your exploration into Rails

Answer (score 0):

If you change this

```
<%= f.input :user_id, collection: User.all, label_method: :full_name %>
```

to

```
(some place in you view - or in the controller)
<% <your object>.user_id = <current user id> %>
...
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
```

I think it will work

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have already tried that. The solution should be somewhere in the create method for the status controller